# Passing ES6 class to Workerize

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, web-worker

Is it possible to pass an ES6 class to [Workerize](https://github.com/developit/workerize)? For example,

worker.ts

```
export class SampleClass implements SampleInterface {
    private classInfo: string;
    public getClassInfo() {
        return this.classInfo;
    }
}
```

index.ts

```
const worker = workerize(SampleClass)
```

and then I could do something like `worker.getClassInfo()` wherever (in my case, importing it is an NPM package)?

Comment: What is workerize?

Comment: https://github.com/developit/workerize - library by developit for offloading a module into a web worker

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for not seeing this earlier - workerize only supports functions.  If you need to proxy more complex interfaces, I would recommend using [comlink](https://github.com/googlechromelabs/comlink).

There's also [comlink-loader](https://github.com/googlechromelabs/comlink-loader) if you're using Webpack, which is pretty much identical to workerize-loader except supports classes and callbacks and all that stuff.